# How should I name objects that are extending Android's base objects

Tags: java, android, code-reuse

I'm creating a custom TextView in Android, which extends android.widget.TextView. What is the best practice to name this object. Should I just name it as TextView or ProjTextView.

If I name it just TextView, programmers should be careful to declare it as follows to avoid clash with android.widget.TextView

```
proj.base.TextView tv = new proj.base.TextView();
```

on the other hand, if I use ProjTextView, it gets simple

```
ProjTextView tv = new ProjTextView();
```

I'm actually building a generic-purpose library of all controls, with a few additional functionality, nothing specific to a particular project. Just want to know from the Java experts the right way to name these controls.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You should name it after what it is and what it does. What's the difference between the android TextView and yours?

If you are only subclassing to change the look of the TextView, then consider using a style and/or theme.

Comment: Sorry, edited my question. Its actually a generic purpose component, nothing specific to a project. Am adding a few additional properties to make developer's task easier - for example setTooltip. I'm building  library of ALL android controls...

Comment: As aromero said. Give it a new name that is project independent. Btw, I would never give a class a project dependent name.